# How to use scope variables with the "Controller as" syntax in Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm using jasmine for angularJS testing. In my views, I'm using the "Controller as" syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="configCtrl as config">
    <div> {{ config.status }} </div>
</div>
```

How can I use these "scope" variables in jasmine? What does the "Controller as" refer to?
My test looks like following:

```
describe('ConfigCtrl', function(){
    var scope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('busybee'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $controller('configCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it('should have text = "any"', function(){
        expect(scope.status).toBe("any");
    });
});
```

Calling `scope.status` ends, for sure, with the error:

```
Expected undefined to be "any".
```

**UPDATE**: Controller (compiled javascript from TypeScript) looks like this:

```
var ConfigCtrl = (function () {
    function ConfigCtrl($scope) {
        this.status = "any";
    }
    ConfigCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    return ConfigCtrl;
})();
```

Comment: At least, you should do `expect(scope.config.status).toBe("any");`

Comment: Please provide the code for `configCtrl` the as syntax is almost like doing `$scope.config = this;` and doing `this.status = "any";`.

Comment: It works if I define `$scope.config = this;` manually in my controller. But I think it's not the way it's supposed to be, isn't it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The solution is to use the "controller as" syntax when instantiating your controller in your test. Specifically:

$controller('**configCtrl as config**', {$scope: scope});

expect(**scope.config.status**).toBe("any");

The following should now pass:

```
describe('ConfigCtrl', function(){
    var scope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('busybee'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($controller,$rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $controller('configCtrl as config', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it('should have text = "any"', function(){
        expect(scope.config.status).toBe("any");
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I get the error `Error: Argument 'configCtrl as config' is not a function, got undefined in path/to/angular.js (line 1039)` at the line `$controller('configCtrl as config', {$scope: scope});`

Comment: Should work, see AngularJS own test code for "controller as" feature over here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/test/ng/controllerSpec.js#L112

Comment: @3x14159265 Two other things to check/try: (1) inject $controller, e.g. `beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {`. and (2) make sure your module where configCtrl is defined is loaded. I'm using this syntax in AngularJS 1.2.0 RC3 without any errors.

Comment: Works! Thanks. This should be flagged as the answer.

Answer (score 15):

When we are using the `controller as` syntax, there should be no need to inject $rootScope into our test.  The following should work just fine.

```
describe('ConfigCtrl', function(){
    beforeEach(module('busybee'));

    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
        ctrl = $controller('ConfigCtrl');
    }));

    it('should have text = "any"', function(){
         expect(ctrl.status).toBe("any");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sometimes you still need access to $scope inside your controller, even if you are using `controller as`